# Graphically display the information collected by powermetrics

Tags: macos

how can I graphically display the information collected by powermetrics in the terminal as bar charts like in the following video?

[image]

[https://youtu.be/2XY_Utsmfvw?t=398](https://youtu.be/2XY_Utsmfvw?t=295)

I am very interested in the cpu/gpu frequency which is often not displayed by other tools. I want to know when my system is thermal throttling.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The tool is asitop https://github.com/tlkh/asitop

It took a while to find it - but managed to find it from one of the Max Tech presenters (source: https://twitter.com/VadimYuryev/status/1455577577691570177?s=20 )

M

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @malliemcg Thanks :) I searched so long and did not find it!

Answer (score 7):

The `powermetrics` command that comes with macOS does not have a text interface as the one screenshotted with charts, etc. It does however collect information and write them out in a standard format that makes it easy to create a small program that parses it and displays it in charts, etc.

As an example of such a program, you can take a look at this open source project:

https://github.com/singhkays/apple-m1-power-consumption-powermetrics

It takes the data collected by `powermetrics`, parses it and generates nice looking charts for use on for example a blog or web site.

Another example is `asitop`:

https://github.com/tlkh/asitop

As seen in the screenshot here from [an extensive M1 benchmark](https://tlkh.dev/benchmarking-the-apple-m1-max):

[image: Screenshot of asitop]

Answer (score 3):

There is another GUI tool: [Mx Power Gadget](https://www.seense.com/menubarstats/mxpg/) (Arm analog of Intel Power Gadget)
[image: Mx Power Gadget screenshot]

It can also be installed through [Brew](https://brew.sh/) package manager:

```
brew install mx-power-gadget
```

Comment: are there any alternatives for intel macs?

Comment: `brew install intel-power-gadget` @JohhanSantana